# How can set rtl=false , just for a layer?

Tags: android, manifest, right-to-left

I want to set `rtl = true` in `Manifest` for all `layers` , except one of the layers .
how can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `android:layoutDirection` property in XML, it can have either `rtl` or `ltr` values.

The property overrides `android:supportsRtl` property in `"application"` segment of your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think for all layers you need to define `rtl = true` and for one layer make it false. That should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response.test it but, I did not have any results